# How can I stop my form from reloading on submit?

Tags: html, forms

When I submit this form, I can see that it submitted properly but it always reloads and I lose my progress.

```
<form id="edpiForm" action="#" method="POST" name="edpiForm">

<div id="div-dpi">
<label for="dpi">Dpi: </label>
<input type="number" name="dpi" id="dpi" class="input">
</div>


<div id="div-sens">
<label for="sens">Sensitivity: </label>
<input type="number" name="sens" id="sens" class="input" step="any" >
</div>

<div id="button">
<button id="submitbutton" name="button" onclick="function()">Calculate</button>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply change

```
<button id="submitbutton" name="button" onclick="function()">Calculate</button>
```

to

```
<button type="submit">Calculate</button>
```

JS code:

```js
document.querySelector('#edpiForm').onsubmit = evt =>
  {
  evt.preventDefault() // disable submit

  // code for your calculate button
  // ...
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't condone that brace placement :P

Answer (score 0):

just add type attribute to the button

```
type="button"
```